# c# bind winforms chart to list of objects

Tags: c#, winforms, list, charts, bind

I have a list of objects defined like this:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public int New
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Closed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Canceled
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

How can I bind a winforms-chart (bar-chart type) to a `List<ChartData>`? I need to have a series for each property in the object (ie, I will have 3 series) and for each point in the chart, I want to see the values for all 3 properties in the object.

I managed to programatically add the series (they're visible in the chart), but when I try to set the data source, it crashes:

```
        List<ChartData> data = new List<ChartData>();
        // fill with random int values
        chart.DataSource = data;

        chart.Series.Add("New").XValueMember = "New";
        chart.Series["New"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series["New"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chart.Series["New"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

        chart.Series.Add("Canceled").XValueMember = "Canceled";
        chart.Series["Canceled"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series["Canceled"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chart.Series["Canceled"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

        chart.Series.Add("Closed").XValueMember = "Closed";
        chart.Series["Closed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series["Closed"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chart.Series["Closed"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

        chart.DataBind();
```

with an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, saying that `Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series.` ...

Any help/hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `XValueMember` with `YValueMembers` :

```
        chart.Series.Add("New").YValueMembers = "New";
        chart.Series["New"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series["New"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chart.Series["New"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

        chart.Series.Add("Canceled").YValueMembers = "Canceled";
        chart.Series["Canceled"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series["Canceled"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chart.Series["Canceled"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;

        chart.Series.Add("Closed").YValueMembers = "Closed";
        chart.Series["Closed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart.Series["Closed"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        chart.Series["Closed"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
```

[image]