# Set up a chart to draw points dynamically from a Class List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, charts

So i have a Class `List <Entry>` which looks like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4.Models
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public string Segment { get; set; }
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public double Speed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The populated list has about 70 list items.
I've had problems feeding the List as a source to the Chart. I'd like the Time values to be the marks on the X axis, and Speed values to be the points on the said X mark. The picture illustrates:

[image]

I've tried the solution posted [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608235/c-sharp-bind-winforms-chart-to-list-of-objects), no errors but my chart shows up just an empty area. The code in the Form1 is:

```
        chart1 = new Chart();

        chart1.DataSource = list;

        chart1.Series.Add("Speed").YValueMembers = "Speed";
        chart1.Series["Speed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        chart1.Series["Speed"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
        chart1.Series["Speed"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
```

Any Advice how to bind the List as the datasource for the chart? The forums are rather scarce on said topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<Entry>
        {
            new Entry {Time = 1, Speed = 80, Segment = "Seg 1" },
            new Entry {Time = 2, Speed = 40, Segment = "Seg 2" },
            new Entry {Time = 3, Speed = 100, Segment = "Seg 3" },
            new Entry {Time = 4, Speed = 20, Segment = "Seg 4" },
            new Entry {Time = 5, Speed = 60, Segment = "Seg 5" },
        };

        chart1 = new Chart();
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");

        chart1.Series.Add("Speed");
        chart1.Series["Speed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart1.Series["Speed"].XValueMember = "Time";
        chart1.Series["Speed"].YValueMembers = "Speed";

        chart1.DataSource = list;
        chart1.DataBind();

        Controls.Add(chart1);
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Adding a button `Click` event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1 = new Chart();
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");

        chart1.Series.Add("Speed");
        chart1.Series["Speed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart1.Series["Speed"].XValueMember = "Time";
        chart1.Series["Speed"].YValueMembers = "Speed";

        list = new List<Entry>();

        chart1.DataSource = list;

        panel1.Controls.Add(chart1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Add(new Entry { Time = i, Speed = i * 10, Segment = i.ToString() });
        chart1.DataBind();

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but only in a fresh project where all of the code is within the `Form1_load` event.  In my application, I get the list after some processing and when i put this code down the line, the chart is also blank. Are there some lines of code that have to be in the form load event for it to work?

Comment: Please see my updated code sample using a button `Click` event to add data.

Comment: However, I'm experiencing some visual issues with the chart. [LINK](http://imgur.com/zFyI8vw) See the image, the first one is in the designer look, the second one is the application when running. It seems the designer one just stays on top of the one created by the data. Is this a known issue, how do I make the designer version of the chart invisible?

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly the problem is based only on the pictures.... The best policy would be for you to post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In case i can't help, someone else will.

Comment: Wild guess but you're probably adding one chart at design time and another one at run time....

Comment: Both ways are OK but you have to make up your mind which method you're going to use. Using VS Designer saves a lot of time and coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113466/discussion-between-romy-and-jstreet).